# Can't Access File In file:///android_asset

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a file `myfile.vtpk` in my application's `"Assets"` folder.

I'm trying to load this file file in my application using the following:

```
            Uri vtpkUri = new Uri("file:///android_asset/myfile.vtpk");
            ArcGISVectorTiledLayer vtpkLayer = new ArcGISVectorTiledLayer(vtpkUri);

            MyMapView.Map.OperationalLayers.Add(vtpkLayer);
```

I get no error, but the file is never loaded.

How can I access this file in Android?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot speak for what Xamarin does, but in ordinary Android app development, `file:///android_asset` is something used by `WebView`, but little else.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Can you please point me to a sample on how to load a file in Android? I can't seem to access a file, no matter where I put it. It seems there is a specific directory where it must go, but I just cannot find it.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I've seen on forums people referencing file:///mnt/sdcard/map.vtpk, but I don't know where to find that directory in the application to store the file initially.

Comment: Using `assets/` is fine. However, that is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device. In ordinary Android app development, you access an asset by calling `getAssets().open()` on a `Context`, with the relative path to the asset (`myfile.vtpk` in your case). This gives you an `InputStream` to the asset's content.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I see. I don't really need to open the file though, I just have to find it and pass it's location as a URI to ArcGISVectorTiledLayer. It just won't allow me to do that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a file in your Assets folder is compiled into your APK, there is no "Uri" for a file in your assets folder, or any file in your APK for that matter. If you need to be able to pass a Uri, you would want to copy the Asset to your Document or other folder for your app and then get the Uri.

First create a method to take an read stream and write write stream and write your asset to a file:

```
private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
{
    int Length = 256;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
    int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    // write the required bytes
    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
          writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
           bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    }
    readStream.Close();
    writeStream.Close();
}
```

Then get the read stream from the asset:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = Assets.OpenFd("filenameinAssetsfolder.ext");
var readStream = afd.CreateOutputStream();
```

Then create the path for the file and the write stream:

```
// This will be your final file path
var pathToWriteFile = 
    Path.Combine (System.Environment.GetFolderPath 
    (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), 
    "filenametowrite.ext"); 
FileStream writeStream = 
    new FileStream(pathToWriteFile, 
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
    FileAccess.Write);
```

And finally call the copy method created above:

```
ReadWriteStream(readStream, writeStream);
```

Now you should be able to access the file with the path in `pathToWriteFile`.

EDIT: As per the comment below, try the following instead of getting an AssetFileDescriptor first. Replace:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = Assets.OpenFd("filenameinAssetsfolder.ext");
var readStream = afd.CreateOutputStream();
```

with:

```
Stream readStream = Assets.Open("filenameinAssetsfolder.ext");
```

Comment: @jgoldberger- I keep getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed`. It's a .vtpk file. Is there any way around that error?

Comment: Hmm.. try just using Assets.Open(...) instead of Assets.OpenFd(...). Answer edited to show this option.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. You are amazing. I will go ahead and accept your answer.